# How to require a config file in a template and in function.php?

Tags: functions, templates

I made a config.php file where I store some arrays for configuration like LDAP and other things.
I need to call it on different templates but I also need to require it into function.php.

When I do this this, I have warning and all my tables become Undefined.

**EDIT**

I found this solution : call my config.php into functions.php with : `require ( get_template_directory() . '/config.php' );`

Replaced this require from all my tempate/views by `global $ARRAY_NAME;`

Comment: Show some code?

Answer (score 0):

It is depends on where your `config.php` file is located. Write code in active theme's `functions.php`

1. If file is on root of WordPress installtion:
   `require_once(ABSPATH .'config.php');`
2. If it is on active Theme's root directory: `require_once('config.php');`

Answer (score 0):

@Baikare Sandeep : Hi, it is not a path problem. my config.php is at the theme's root. I can access it in my templates and functions.php with `require ( get_template_directory() . '/config.php' );`